# Why is RSP affected after this XOR?

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I'm in trouble trying to figure out why **RSP** gets affected after a simple "**XOR RAX, R8**". I provide here a view of before and after single-stepping this instruction so you can see the problem by yourself.
I had never experienced this weird situation by the past.

Context before:

[image: RSP before]

Context after:

[image: RSP after]

**SOLVED** : The issue actually came from the plugin I was using with gdb (pwndbg), when I use gdb with gef I get no error.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think it would be clear for people

Comment: It's not code but a debugger view by the way

Comment: `rax` before and after `xor` has the same value and should not according to the values from the screenshot.

Comment: yes you are right, I don't get it

Comment: Okay, I get it, it comes from the plugin I use with gdb (pwndbg), I tried with gef and can't reproduce. I'm really surprised of that behaviour.

Comment: Bugs in a debugger are nasty. :/  But yeah, it's clearly impossible for `XOR RAX, R8` to affect RSP.  It can't even fault, although a signal could be delivered after it executes, changing RSP.

Comment: Debugger output counts as "results". Everything should be text if possible, since screen-readers can't deal with screenshots.